# How many different possible structures (isomers) are there for the complex, [Mn(OH2)3(NH3)3] 3+?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

How many different possible structures (isomers) are there for the complex,
$\ce{[Mn(OH2)3(NH3)3]^{3+}}$?

I really don't know how to begin with this. I know the answer is 2, but i don't have the faintest idea how this is the case. Since $\ce{Mn}$ has a charge of $3+$, I know that its valence electron configuration is $3d^4$. I also know that $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ are monodentate, which means they contribute 1 lone pair.

Comment: Try sketching a few possible configurations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Metal complexes with three each of two types of ligands $(\ce{MX3Y3})$ have two isomers: [*mer*- and *fac*-isomers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fac%E2%80%93mer_isomerism#Cis.E2.80.93trans_isomerism_and_facial.E2.80.93meridional_isomerism). For example, for $\ce{Co(NH3)3Cl3}$ there are two isomers:

> *Fac* for facial, in which all three ligands of each type are clustered on a single face of the octahedron and the three other three ligands are on the opposite face.

[image]

> *Mer* for meridional, in which the three ligands of each type are arranged meridianally in a row around the metal and the other three ligands are arranged likewise on the opposite side in a perpendicular meridian.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The compound you talked about is of the type $MA_3B_3$. I will illustrate a similar example here.
There shall be 2 geometrical isomers, '***FACIAL***' and '***MERIDONAL***'

[image]

> To identify which is which, remember that in *MERIDONAL* maximum bond
>   angles between the groups is **180** whereas in facial it is lesser
>   than that. Also **none** of them is optically active as both have a
>   Plane of symmetry (*merdional* has *diagonal POS whereas facial has
>   horizontal*).

Therefore the compound has total **2 STRUCTURAL ISOMERS** (*2 GEOMETRICAL + 0 OPTICAL*).